# JS Array: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have an important number of html elements dynamically created when clicking a button. In JS they look like this:

```
var elementTVA = document.createElement('p');
```

In order to manipulate quickly those elements, I have decided to store them in an array and use a for loop.

```
for (var i=0 ; i<=tableau.length ; i++) {
        tableau[i].classList.add('list-element');
        newRow.appendChild(tableau[i]);
    };
```

However I get this error when I try to append them

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Is it because I store them in an array?

Comment: `i < tableau.length ` , array indices go from 0 to *one **smaller** then length* , basically you exit the arrays range.

Comment: You need to show the code that populates `tableau`.

Comment: thanks (beginner mistake -_-)

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop, you should use

```
for (var i=0; i < tableau.length; i++) {
```

You should be checking if `i` is *less than* the length, instead of *less than or equal to*.

An array's length will be one higher than the largest index because arrays start at `0`, so when you access `tableau[ tableau.length ]`, you get `undefined`.